# Adding a border

Tags: c++, border

I'm trying to complete my border. Currently it looks like this...

```
       ************************************
       *Body and Soul
       *Tenor Madness
       *Impressions
       *Lester Leaps In
       *There Will Never Be Another You
       *Summertime
       *Blues In The closet
       *Maiden Voyage
       ***********************************
```

---

How do I get the right side of the border? Assuming that there will never be a sentence longer than "there will never be another you".?

```
 void print(string list_array[]){

    for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
        cout << '*';
    }

    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        cout<<'*' <<list_array[i] << endl;
   }
    for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
        cout <<'*';
   }
    cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: just print blank space after each string, and end the line with `"*\n"`

Comment: But then it won't look like a rectangle...the right side will be uneven.

Comment: `std::setw` is your friend.

Comment: check the string length, using `std::length()` print as many blank spaces as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::setw` or you need to fill with space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void print( std::vector<std::string> &stringVec ) {
    cout << std::setfill( '*' ) << setw( 40 ) << '*' <<  endl;
    for( int i=0; i< stringVec.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << '*' << std::left << setfill(' ' )<< setw( 40 - 2 ) << stringVec[i] << '*'<< endl;
    }
    cout << std::setfill( '*' ) << setw( 40 ) << '*' <<  endl;
}

int main( )
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "Body and Soul",
        "Tenor Madness",
        "Impressions",
        "Lester Leaps In",
        "There Will Never Be Another You",
        "Summertime" "Blues In The closet",
        "Maiden Voyage" };
    print( vec );
}
```

Output:

```
****************************************
*Body and Soul                         *
*Tenor Madness                         *
*Impressions                           *
*Lester Leaps In                       *
*There Will Never Be Another You       *
*SummertimeBlues In The closet         *
*Maiden Voyage                         *
****************************************
```

Comment: Using `std::setfill` with `std::setw` is better than output filling character by loop. By the way, my demo need to be compiled with `-std=c++11`, for using of initializer list.